# How to automate creating hive views (like 40+ views) for data on hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Is there any tool to automatically create hive view queries ? Instead of writing 30+ view query  and generate 30+ queries using any tools which saves time

Comment: Why not write the code to make the query yourself?